# Replayed Safe Using Function CreateProxyWithNonce of Safe Factory Proxy 0xa6B71E26C5e0845f74c812102Ca7114b6a896AB2 dosn't allow me to interact with

Tags: safe-core-sdk, safe-core, migration, safe

## Help Needed

I Replayed a Safe Using Function `CreateProxyWithNonce` of Safe Factory Proxy `0xa6B71E26C5e0845f74c812102Ca7114b6a896AB2` and this Safe doesn't allow me to interact with SAFE UI, **I need to interact using SAFECLI.**

[image: SAFE Warning]

### Safe UI shows that my Safe Version is 1.3.0

[image: Safe Version]

### When I load it in SAFECLI it shows me the option to Update to a new version.

Should I execute the `Update` command? Or maybe should I use the `update_version_to_l2` command? My version is 1.3.0

[image: SAFE CLI]

Answer (score 0):

Updating to an L2 contract is not mandatory, as it only adds more events to your current safe. If you are in the process of trying to recover a safe, we advise not to do this as it could have an impact on your ability to recover your funds.

The `Update` command is not necessary in your case as v1.3.0 is currently the most stable version, supported on most contracts. It will not make your safe usable on the Wallet UI. So I would recommend to first recover your funds; optionally update a newer version; then update to an l2 safe only if everything went fine.

Hope it helps, please let me know if I can help further.